# Parse a "Server Hello" from a capture using pyOpenSSL

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

I have some PCAPs of TLS exchanges to debug. I'd like to extract things from a "Server Hello" message the way that OpenSSL would.

I have what the server sent available as a `bytes` object. It starts with `b'\x16\x03\x03` for handshake type, TLS version 1.2. [Here](https://screenshots.firefox.com/SBU0ND1hFtpqYga6/null) is an example of what Wireshark sees.

It seems like pyOpenSSL must be able to interpret such an object, as that's what OpenSSL would see coming from the network in real life. Reading through pyOpenSSL's [unit tests](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/37e6022e8a907ef52a3eba4c53edac8c32bedfc0/tests/test_ssl.py#L300), it looks like it's possible to simulate data coming in from the wire.

However, I've been unable to get this to work:

```
from OpenSSL.SSL import Connection, Context, TLSv1_2_METHOD

context = Context(TLSv1_2_METHOD)
conn = Connection(context, None)
conn.set_connect_state()
conn.bio_write(b'\x16\x03\x03...')  # this goes on for a while
conn.do_handshake()
```

The error is `OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_hello', 'parse tlsext')]`, which is sort of promising - it's doing *something*. Writing a "Client Hello" instead of a "Server Hello" correctly gives an `unexpected message`, and writing gibberish gives a `wrong version number` error (which also makes sense).

My goal is to be able to make the [`Connection.get_` methods](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/ssl.html#OpenSSL.SSL.Connection.get_app_data) returning data from this replayed data. Is it possible to do, or does pyOpenSSL not expose the necessary bits of OpenSSL?

Comment: No specific ideas but two comments: 1) PyOpenSSL is just a wrapper around openssl libraries, and it may not expose everything you need, so maybe trying directly at the openssl level (in C) instead of in Python might help. The library may have also unit tests like you are trying to do. and 2) based on the error message maybe the library version (openssl) is not good enough, and it does not recognize a specific TLS extension. So you should at least specify which versions do you use in your question.

Comment: ...  You could try by generating real TLS handshakes with the specific openssl you got on the host and then trying to reparse them manually as you would have the result of `openssl s_client` to compare your python case with.

Comment: I was pretty sure my extensions were nothing special, but I did check an `s_client` / `s_server` connection locally. Replaying that gets further, but I get `('rsa routines', 'int_rsa_verify', 'bad signature'), ('SSL routines', 'tls_process_key_exchange', 'bad signature')` - which of course makes sense.